# not able to edit authentication header based on path location in Apache virtualhost?

Tags: apache

The application for which Apache is reverse proxy behaves like this:

1. It requires basic authentication header to login to it.
2. For the paths starting from `/api/*` requires just Bearer token.
3. If there is basic token in header, the application returns 401, unauthorized http response - it requires needs only Bearer token.

CAS authentication is configured for all the URLs except `/api/*` path and I am setting the base authentication token inside vhost config file - to login a user without presenting a login form again after he/she authenticates with CAS.

Apache config file `enterprise-search.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName https://search.test.xyz
        ServerAdmin john@xyz

    RemoteIPHeader X-Client-IP
    RemoteIPInternalProxy 10.10.10.2
    LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined-forwarded

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/enterprise-search-access.log combined-forwarded
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/enterprise-search-error.log

    LogLevel debug
    
        CASRootProxiedAs https://search.xyz
    
    <Location />
        # authn type
        AuthType CAS
        CASScope /
        AuthName "KFUPM"
        # authz
        # Grant all groups access to the root
        AuthGroupFile "/etc/apache2/http-authz/enterprise-search"
        Require group all-enterpirse-search
        # Pass REMOTE_USER header to application
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)$
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
        RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic xxxxxxxxxx"
    </Location>

    # authz: local_groups
        <Location /all-enterpirse-search>
        AuthGroupFile "/etc/apache2/http-authz/enterprise-search"
        Require group all-enterprise-search all-enterpirse-search
    </Location>
        
    <Location /api/>
        # authn type
        AuthType none
        Allow from all
        Satisfy any
        
        # authz
        Require valid-user
        # Pass REMOTE_USER header to application
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)$
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
        RequestHeader edit Authorization "Basic[^,]+, " ""

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3002/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3002/
    </Location>    
    
</VirtualHost>
```

The behavior of `RequestHeader edit Authorization "Basic[^,]+, " ""` is to replace Basic token header that is passed by the client and it works fine.

But what I actually want is to set Basic token in `<Location />` and remove it in `<Location /api/>`. Using `RequestHeader edit Authorization "Basic[^,]+, " ""` inside `<Location /api/>` is not removing the basic token and the application is returning the API call with 401 response.

I am new to Apache configs, may be my approach to achieve my goal is not correct. Please suggest if there is better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pull this of because you want proxy path for both your Authorization and for your applications.
but you can make just your api at front and make CAS path to something like /auth and redirect to CAS by your api.